# PdfBox: PDFMergerUtility How to reuse the object?

Tags: java, pdfbox

```
/*PDFMergerUtility mergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();*/


 while(rs.next())
    {


        PDFMergerUtility mergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();

        try
           {
            in=resultset.getBinaryStream(1);
            mergerUtility.addSource(in);
            mergerUtility.setDestinationStream(bos);
            mergerUtility.mergeDocuments();

           }

    catch (Exception e) 
       { 

       }
        bos.reset();
       /*How to reset/clear mergeutility object?*/
   }
```

If not instantiating, PDFMergerUtility mergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility(); inside while loop, gives end of file error.. How to reuse it without declaring in while loop?

Comment: I don't know if I get it but did you try to declare outside the while loop and initialize it inside the loop?

Comment: @Averroes: By initializing u mean instantiating it inside the loop?

Comment: Something like this. `PDFMergerUtility mergerUtility = null; while(rs.next()) { mergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility(); ...`

Comment: @Averroes: mergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility(); also means recreating new instance every time in the loop.

Comment: In the documentation I didn't find any way to clear/reset the PDFMergerUtility. What's the problem with creating a new instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are not merging. To fix, the code will be like this

```
    PDFMergerUtility mergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();
    try  {
        while(rs.next())    {      
            in=resultset.getBinaryStream(1);
            mergerUtility.addSource(in);

        }       
        mergerUtility.setDestinationStream(bos);
        mergerUtility.mergeDocuments();

        bos.close();

   }
   catch (Exception e) { 

   }
```